# PHP mail() force single recipient

Tags: php, email

What is the best way to force mail() to send only to first recipient, even if user provides multiple recipients in `$email`... I need to filter user input somehow...?

```
$email = '1@mail.com, 2@mail.com, 3@mail.com...';    
mail( $email, $subject, $body, $extra )  //send to: 1@mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You could explode the string by comma and only throw the first element of the resulting array in mail().

```
$email = '1@mail.com, 2@mail.com, 3@mail.com...';
$recips = explode(",", $email);
if(filter_var(trim($recips[0]), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
    mail(trim($recips[0]), $subject, $body, $extra )  //send to: 1@mail.com
} else {
    die("no valid email");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that this is a valid email: ","@mail.com

Comment: You could use [filter_var()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to validate if it's an email.

Answer (score 0):

You may write:

```
$emails = explode(',',$email);
```

Now `$emails[0]` is the first email you can use in the `mail()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the user does not separate the adresses by using a comma. then this will not work and just `trim()`ing the adress will also not prevent you from giving multiple emails to `mail()`. 
You will somehow also need to check the adress to prevent syntax errors, f.e. using `filter_var()`:

```
$emails = explode(',', $email);
$email = filter_var(trim($emails[0]), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($email === false) {
    exit();
}
```

some more sophisticated checking can also be done using regular expressions:

```
$regex = "/^[a-zA-Z\d][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z\d]@[a-zA-Z\d][\w\.-]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/i";
$emailString = '1@mail.com, 2@mail.com, 3@mail.com...';
$emailArray = explode(',', $emailString);
$isValdid = preg_match($regex, $emails[0]);
if ($isValid === 0) { // 1 for match, 0 for mismatch, false for error
    echo "please supply a valid adress.";
}
```

Comment: This solution with regex is ok but it's not a solution of this problem because it throws an error, and I MUST send email (just not to each recipient)... PS. what else can be used to separate emails?

Comment: I have edited my answer. @NisseEngström hard-wiring TLDs was silly, you're right.
Now i check the first email for correctness, but you have to take into consideration that a user could also supply an incorrect adress, and then you cannot send and have to throw an error. to separate emails, any character that is not valid inside an email can be used.